# HTTP POST Not Working (408 Error)

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, webserver

I am having some problems trying to get a post request to work from a payment provider (WorldPay) to my host server. Basically WorldPay does a callback to a script on my website if/when a transaction is successful. Problem is the post request isn’t getting to my script – we just get a 408 timeout.

This is the request sent from WorldPay below:

```
POST /index.php?route=payment/worldpay/callback HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: www.mysite.com
Content-Length: 711
User-Agent: WJHRO/1.0 (WorldPay Java HTTP Request Object)

authAmountString=%26%23163%3B3.49&_SP.charEnc=UTF-8&desc=testItem&authMode=A
```

And this is the response sent back from my hosts server:

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
Connection: Close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I know this is a long shot but can anyone see anything wrong with anything above? To simplify things i replaced the php script with a basic html output which returned a hello world message and we still got a 408 so i’m pretty sure the script works. We have also had this error once or twice:

```
failed CAUSED BY invalid HTTP status line: >null<
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Cheers

Paul

Comment: is there any chance the request WorldPay send is https ?

Comment: no it's definitly not no - why do you ask?

Comment: because i can't no reason so i'm looking for alternative solutions :-)

Comment: Are you testing this on your localhost or an actual website?

Comment: both - have tested it on my local machine and web server

Comment: could it be something to do with the different http protocols i.e. http 1.0 and http 1.1 or should they be ok? same with the 2 different char sets??

Comment: What exactly is the index.php doing?
Any chance, that the provider needs to get some kind of "OK" String or any other answer from the index.php.

Answer (score 2):

If the HTTP request you gave above is accurate, it seems as if the client is advertising a content length of 711 bytes, but the entity body does not seem to be 711 bytes long. That is why the server is timing out waiting for the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout,

pay attention to server config, if your host server is nginx, you can check "client_body_timeout" in nginx.conf